# Delegating @classmethods in python

Tags: python, delegation

I need a delegated class to delegate a `@classmethod`.  Here's what I've tried:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def from_a(cls, a):
        return cls(a)

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, foo):
        elf._foo = foo

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._foo, name)
```

But, of course this doesn't define how to look up attributes of `Foo` (not of an instance of `Foo`), so `Bar.from_a(5)` will raise an `AttributeError`.  While it is of course possible to do this explicitly by defining a `from_a` method on `Bar` or to do this at instantiation by calling `Bar(Foo.from_a(5))`, I would rather do this implicitly.  Ideas?

Comment: Instances of `Foo` *have* the class method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why? Obviously `from_a` does not exist on `Bar` as you didn't define it or subclass `Foo`. Why do you expect it to?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But the questioner is looking for ways to make `Bar.from_a(5)` work, so there's no instance of `Foo` in sight.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ah, I see what you mean. Then you need a metaclass.

Comment: @SteveJessop: But the class doesn't have any reference to another class. It cannot be a proxy for an arbitrary class. The meta class should be told what class to proxy for, or there must be a class attribute.

Comment: @Martijn: I was thinking metaclass too, but I was also thinking that on balance the questioner probably *doesn't* need a metaclass so much as to do something that makes more sense. I'm still trying to work out why `Bar` doesn't just inherit from `Foo`...

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'll delete my answer, there is not enough info here.

Comment: @classmethod def from_a( cls, target, a ): return cls( target.from_a(a) )
is about the only thing making sense — the target class has to come from somewhere…

Comment: @jhermann The target class is apparently Foo.

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and created an answer using a metaclass (which is horribly complex compared to the alternatives), but it still does require knowing the target class in advance.

Comment: I loathe drive-by questions like this, with no followup. Now there are several "answers" of varying complexity, each solving a wild guess of what is actually wanted.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Sorry.  I posted this last thing before leaving work and was out and about for the night.

Comment: @LennartRegebro As stated in the question, I'm trying to create a delegate class (e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643538/delegates-in-python)) of `Foo` with `Bar`.  In this case, I'm doing this to avoid the need to subclass `PIL.Image` since the `open` method of that doesn't actually return an object of the same class (it returns a subclass).

Comment: So you aren't doing `Bar.from_a(5)` at all, you are doing `b.from_a(5)`, where `b = Bar(Foo)`?

Comment: No, I'd be doing `Bar.from_a(5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started working on what I thought would be a simple approach for this using a metaclass, but it is actually fairly complex.  What you should probably be doing here is having `Bar` inherit from `Foo`, but I'll show you what I came up with all the same:

```
import types
import functools

def make_delegating_type(delegatee):
    class DelegatingType(type):
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            obj = getattr(delegatee, name)
            if isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
                @functools.wraps(obj)
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    result = obj(*args, **kwargs)
                    if isinstance(result, delegatee):
                        return self(result)
                    return result
                return wrapper
            return obj
    return DelegatingType

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a): self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def from_a(cls, a): return cls(a)

class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = make_delegating_type(Foo)
    def __init__(self, foo): self._foo = foo

    def __getattr__(self, name): return getattr(self._foo, name)
```

Note that in 3.x you would use `class Bar(object, metaclass=make_delegating_type(Foo)` instead of the `__metaclass__ = make_delegating_type(Foo)` line at the top of the `Bar` class body.

Here is how this works.  Your current version currently delegates attribute lookups on instances of `Bar` to an instance of `Foo`, this uses a metaclass so that attributes lookups on the *class* `Bar` are delegated to the *class* `Foo` as well.  Unfortunately it is not as simple as just using a `__getattr__` definition that returns `getattr(delegatee, name)`, because if the attribute your a looking up is a factory function as in your example you need a version of that factory function that will return an instance of your delegating type.  So for example `Bar.from_a(5)` should be the same as `Bar(Foo.from_a(5))`, and with the naive approach you would just get `Foo.from_a(5)`.  That is why there is all the logic detecting if the attribute is a function or method, and creating a wrapper that checks the return type of that function/method.

To reiterate, **I do not recommend that you use this code!**  It is much more complicated then just defining `from_a` on `Bar` or having `Bar` inherit from `Foo`.  But hopefully it will be a learning experience for you, as it was for me.

Comment: `Bar` can't inherit from `Foo` in this case.  It does need to be a delegated class or a proxy class.  Check the comments.